# OCaml - Modify array values

Tags: arrays, ocaml

I want to modify an existing array with this function but for a reason I don't understand once I apply the function to the array the values do not change.
What am i missing ?

Thanks in advance

```
let test v (a,b) = 
for i=a to b do
    if ((Array.get v i)>(Array.get v i+1)) then
        let tmp = (Array.get v i) in
            v.(i)<-(Array.get v i+1); 
            v.(i+1)<-tmp;           
done;;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is in Array.get v i+1 : this infers that v is an int array, and that you add 1 and make the condition always false.
Just put i+1 in parenthesis : v will be an array of any type, and it will solve your issue.

```
let test v (a,b) = 
for i=a to b do
    if Array.get v i > Array.get v (i+1) then
        let tmp = (Array.get v i) in
            v.(i)<-(Array.get v (i+1)); 
            v.(i+1)<-tmp;           
done;;
```

You could have written using v.(i) > v.(i+1).

Answer (score 4):

The best practice is to put white spaces at function applications including binary operators.

Many newcomers tend to misunderstand

```
Array.get v i+1
```

as `Array.get v (i+1)` but if it is written like

```
Array.get v i + 1
```

then the chance of mistake should go much lower.